# Multiple f:ajax requests from browser for single event

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, triggers

In our application, while clicking buttons by some random users we are receiving multiple requests to our webserver. On analysis we found that upto 4 requests are coming per sec. There are cases where a user tried to login 750 times a day. But all these are genuine users and has no chance of hacking.

Most of the buttons which we use are in the same format as below.

```
<h:commandLink id="login"  title="Click here to login" class="qmBtnPurple">
    <span>#{i18n.getMsg().get("FFP_LOG_LOGIN")}</span>
    <f:ajax execute="@form" onevent="dataValidation" 
            listener="#{loginHandler.login}" render="loginMessage"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

dataValidation() is a simple javascript method which displays an overlay when user clicks the button. So this wont allow the user to click the button multiple times.
Handlers are both request and session scoped.

This is happening from all the browsers and that too for random users. Its also happening in multiple jsf pages. We are using a clustered environment.

Does anyone have any idea regarding this issue. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try different possibilities? What happens if you remove the `onevent` call? Which JSF version implementation are you using?

Comment: Multiple requests to do what exactly. I can see that il8n code there resulting in multiple requests

Comment: We are using JSF 2. Below is webserver logs:                  198.36.39.182 - - [11/Jan/2014:02:11:10 +0300] "GET /ffponline/ffp-online/login.jsf HTTP/1.1" 302 26 "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
198.36.39.182 - - [11/Jan/2014:02:11:10 +0300] "GET /ffponline/ffp-online/login.jsf HTTP/1.1" 302 26 "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
You can see that login.jsf is invoked more than once from same IP (It goes upto 100 times sometimes). The major problem is that we are unable to replicate the issue as it randomly occur

Comment: Has anyone faced similar issues, as ajax call triggered numerous times on a single user event. Can we filter out the simultaneous duplicate request from same IP.

Comment: The following meta tag is added in our layout for proper working of some UI widgets. Will it cause these kind of issues?                   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />